# Using Copy Raster tool to BQA band only

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder, mosaic

I want to do vegetation, water, and soil analysis to an area using satellite imagery. My area of interest is East Java, Indonesia. Here's the map of East Java, Indonesia.

[image: East Java Province]

I got 6 scenes of LANDSAT 8 OLI/TIRS that cover the AOI. I want to combine  all the scenes of all bands (I mosaic Band 1 from 6 scenes, and so on) will shorter my time for analysis because I can analysis all the scenes at once. I build a ModelBuilder for combining the six scenes, band by band. Here's my ModelBuilder.

[image]

The tools I use in the model is Copy Raster to remove the 'black area' (if you know what is it called, please tell) in the georeferenced scene so it doesn't overlap when I combine all the scenes. I set the pixel type 16-bit unsigned, Ignore Value Data 0, and No Data Value 0.

[image: "The Copy Raster Process"]

Then I use Mosaic To New Raster tool to combine all the scenes. I use itu for combining scene in band 1, band 2, band 3, and so on. The model works for band 1 until band 11. But when I use the Model Builder for quality assessment band (BQA), it didn't work.

This is mosaic of six scenes in band number 3 (also my expectation for BQA too), using the ModelBuilder.

[image]

This is the mosaic of the scenes in BQA. The black area isn't removed even when I did the Copy Raster without the ModelBuilder.

[image]

Is it possible to use Copy Raster tool to BQA to remove the 'black area' and then combining all the scenes?

I only find in the internet that Mosaic To New Raster Tool is used for combining composite bands, I don't know if it's okay to combine single band from all scenes, combine to make composite bands, then use it for analysis. I thought is it okay until I find this problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the individual bands the black areas are what are commonly be referred to as NODATA and for each band the value that is NODATA is represented by the value zero.

In the BQA raster the NODATA is referred to as "Fill" as discussed on the page [Landsat Collection 1 Level-1 Quality Assessment Band](https://www.usgs.gov/land-resources/nli/landsat/landsat-collection-1-level-1-quality-assessment-band?qt-science_support_page_related_con=0#qt-science_support_page_related_con). If you query that raster you will discover that this value is represented by the value 1.

Looking at your model your NoData Value element is not a parameter which can be changed by a user so I suspect it's trying to apply 0 when it is 1 in the BQA raster.